# How to not show empty row after data validation LIST

Tags: excel

I have many parts with certain values per month. I listed them as follows:

[image: table with 7 parameters per part, per month]

I would like to create a list via data validation where I pick the name of a part, under which the full list then shows up,

[image: top table shows rows with just zero's. at the bottom only the rows containing data]

I would like to get only the rows that contain a value.

I tried to do it formula based, but is there a way to do this just by selecting the part from the data validation list? Or can this only be done by actively following up with a macro?

Answer (score 0):

File, Options, Advanced, (about 2/3rds of the way down) uncheck "Show a zero in cells that have zero value".